# SET middle of string without changing wildcard

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to update a part of a string for the whole column with something else. For example `1234567890` with `123XXXXX90` except 123 and 90 are not constant throughout the column. This is for Oracle SQL.

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: And do you want the 4th to 8th character replaced or do you want everything except the first 3 chars and last 2 chars replaced?

Comment: Hi Mr. Nair, it's for Oracle SQL

Comment: okay....the initial tags confused me. Good that you've changed those tags.

Comment: To repeat Ashwin's question: is this always between the 4th and 8th character? Or is it always the same sub-string? Or do you always need to keep the first three and last two characters?

Answer (score 1):

For `sql-server`:

```
update yourtable
set col =  concat(left(col, 3), replicate('X', len(col) - 5), right(col,2))
```

For `mysql`:

```
update yourtable
set col =  concat(left(col, 3), repeat('X', length(col) - 5), right(col,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

this is for SQL Server

```
select  stuff('1234567890', 4, 5, 'XXXXX')
```